# Using @Resource injection for Mongo db, inside Web Bundle inside OSGI, under Liberty Profile

Tags: mongodb, osgi, jndi, websphere-liberty

I want to inject Mongo database (com.mongodb.DB) into OSGI Web Bundle Project, using @Resource.

The application is to deployed to WebSphere Liberty Profile V8.5.5.1.

Is this possible to do it?

I got an error message
"....The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

However, I can inject Mongo database into WAR, using @Resource, running on WebSphere Liberty Profile, if not using OSGI.

Below is lookup return null.

```
public static final DB getMongoDB() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    DB lookup = (DB) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/mongo/testdb");
    return lookup;
}
```

The web.xml is

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>mongo/testdb</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>com.mongodb.DB</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

The server.xml is

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>wab-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>blueprint-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>mongodb-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<httpEndpoint host="localhost" httpPort="29080" httpsPort="29443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<library id="MongoLib">
    <file name="${server.config.dir}/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar"/>
</library>
<mongo autoConnectRetry="false" id="mongo" libraryRef="MongoLib">
    <ports>27017</ports>
</mongo>
<mongoDB databaseName="test" id="mongo" jndiName="mongo/testdb" mongoRef="mongo">
</mongoDB>

<osgiApplication id="Test.osgi.jndi.app"
    location="Test.osgi.jndi.app.eba" name="Test.osgi.jndi.app">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="MongoLib"></classloader>
</osgiApplication>
```

Alternatively, I tried to replace the JNDI lookup with below injection. The injected resource returns null.

```
public class MongoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Resource (name="mongo/testdb")
    protected DB db;
}
```

Here is the OSGI Manifest-Version

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test.osgi.jndi.web
Bundle-SymbolicName: Test.osgi.jndi.web
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Web-ContextPath: /Test.osgi.jndi.web
Import-Package: com.mongodb,
 javax.el;version="2.0",
 javax.servlet;version="2.5",
 javax.servlet.annotation,
 javax.servlet.http;version="2.5",
 javax.servlet.jsp;version="2.0",
 javax.servlet.jsp.el;version="2.0",
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext;version="2.0"
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/*.xml
```

The console:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application apps started in 0.054 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:29080/Test.osgi.jndi.web/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application Test.osgi.jndi.app started in 0.561 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0015I: The server has the following interim fixes installed: PI09253.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0046W: The com.mongodb.DB type specified on the resource-ref, resource-env-ref, or message-destination-ref with the osgi:service/mongo/testdb name in the Test.osgi.jndi.web module could not be loaded. Compatibility type checking will not be performed for this resource reference.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the com.osgi.jndi.web.MongoServlet class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.NamingException
[WARNING ] CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the com.osgi.jndi.web.MongoServlet class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.NamingException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:516)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:603)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.getAllDeclaredFields(InjectionProcessor.java:549)
    at [internal classes]
```

Comment: Showing some code (assuming annotations) or config may help in obtaining an answer. If you include this in your question then someone can help.

Comment: I am very sure you miss an import in your Manifest.MF, please add the stacktrace!

Comment: Does your MANIFEST.MF have an Import-Package for javax.naming?

Comment: No. I did not use import-package for javax.naming. Instead, I have "IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile V8.5 JRE", be included in the Java Build Path. I believe that I need not import it explicitly, right?

Comment: I SUSPECT that the "Resource Environment Reference type" in web.xml is incorrect. The OSGI service is defined via "Interface". The conventional JNDI entry is defined via concrete class. Therefore, the "Resource Environment Reference Type" in web.xml is expected to be concrete class type (not interface).

Comment: After further troubleshooting....I add Java Build Entry for Mongodb java driver Deployment Assembly....the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError disappear. However, new exception appears

Comment: @Ross You must use Import-Package for all non-`java.` packages, so yes, you must import `javax.naming`. However, thinking about it further, I don't know if there is an easy way to make MongoDB work from a bundle due to class loading issues; `<mongo>` wants to load classes from a `<library>` class loader, but a WAB wants to load classes from an OSGi class loader.

Comment: @bkail The classloader issue is too difficult for me. finally, I give up using out of the box <mongo> feature, and I write code to directly access mongo; it works.

Answer (score 0):

I add Mongodb Java driver jar into Java Build Path Entry, inside Web Deployment Assembly. The java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError disappears.

However, the JNDI lookup returns new exception, "ClassCastException. I create new post for it.

[ClassCastException during JNDI lookup for MongoDB, inside WAB, running Liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447446/classcastexception-during-jndi-lookup-for-mongodb-inside-wab-running-liberty)

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error. May be you define:
Private MongoServlet mogoServlet;
I don't know why but you try delete this code and replace by some different code. Maybe it will be ok.
It worked for me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question was asked 2 years ago, and the asker has probably given up on it now. Correct answers, however, are always welcome, and can form part of the knowledge base that SO is building. Can you provide some more detail about what you did and whether it was a success (it's not clear right now)