# ClassCastException during JNDI lookup for MongoDB, inside WAB, running Liberty

Tags: mongodb, osgi, jndi, websphere-liberty

I want to use JNDI lookup for MongoDB, inside WAB/OSGi, running Liberty Profile.

```
import com.mongodb.DB;

@WebServlet("/MongoServlet")
public class MongoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            DB db = (DB) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/mongodb");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The JNDI lookup gives below exception.

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.osgi.jndi.web.MongoServlet.doGet:57'
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer incompatible with com.mongodb.DB
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer is subclass of com.mongodb.DB.
```

I believe that the ClassCastException is because of different classloaders being used by my application, and OSGi bootclassloader. But, I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: What is your JNDI context definition?

Comment: I define it inside server.xml of Websphere Liberty Profile, as below   <mongoDB databaseName="test" id="mongo" jndiName="testdb" mongoRef="mongo">
</mongoDB>

Comment: Did you read: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Ftwlp_mongodb_create.html

Comment: Are you using same version of your mongodb jar?

Comment: I am using exactly the same copy of mongodb.jar. I believe that the issue is OSGi bundle is using different classloader; so that the same mongodb.jar are loaded by different classloaders. Even though the class name are the same; they are refering to different thing. Following the instruction of RAD V9 Infocenter, it works perfectly fine - I can use Mongo, in the same way the infocenter describes. I was told by DW fourm, that not includes mongodb.jar in my program, in order to avoid this problem. But I don't know how to "import com.mongodb.DB", without including mongodb.jar in my RAD project.

Comment: I don't think its a classloader issue, otherwise JNDI wouldnt word in OSGi environments. Can you try the following: Object o = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/mongodb"); logger.debug(o.getclass.getname);

Comment: o.getClass().getName() returns "com.mongodb.DBApiLayer"

Comment: Can you add your server.xml?

Comment: I posted the server.xml in different thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281114/using-resource-injection-for-mongo-db-inside-web-bundle-inside-osgi-under-lib?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to use the `mongodb-2.0` feature with an OSGi application.

Looking up a `com.mongodb.DB` resource will return you back an instance of `DBApiLayer`, but that's not the issue (since `DBApiLayer` extends `DB`).  You would still get a ClassCastException even if you did this:

```
DBApiLayer db = (DBApiLayer) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/mongodb");
```

Would throw:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.DBApiLayer incompatible with com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
```

The reason for this limitation is that the `mongodb-2.0` feature will use a Classloader from Liberty to load com.mongodb classes, and an OSGi application will use a separate Classloader to load com.mongodb classes, no matter how you configure things.

Normal Java EE applications can do things like this:

```
<library id="MongoLib">
    <file name="${server.config.dir}/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.11.4.jar"/>
</library>

<application name="myApp">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="MongoLib"/>
</application>
```

However, `<osgiApplication>` elements do not have that capability.  Unfortunately, the only solution here is to open an RFE with IBM (or upvote one if an RFE already exists for this).